# Include 'timestamp' into hash signature with C# and Compact Framework

Tags: c#, cryptography, timestamp, compact-framework, digital-signature

I want to create a hash and sign it from a XML file in C# and Compact Framework 3.5. I obtain a signature of my with success. But now, Now, I want a signature with "trusted timestamp" like it's generated with `CmsSigner` and `Pkcs9SigningTime`.

My code to obtain and sign hash:

```
SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.xml"));

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAprov = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert.PrivateKey;
byte[] signature = RSAprov.SignData(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("sha1"));
```

Is it possible to include `Pkcs9SigningTime` in my signature with Compact Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest is to simply integrate a CMS library such as [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) into your application.